# How can i make a synchronous response to a GET method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to respond a JSON object to a path (e.g. /getAbsencesWithNames). I have used the `includeNames()` function to read data from a JSON file, process it and save it in a the global JSON object i am trying to respond. The problem is the following command `res.end(JSON.stringify(temp, null, "\t"));` executes asynchronously since there is I/O code within `includeNames()` function. How can i make this command wait for my function to complete, in other words make it run synchronously?

```
function includeNames(){
members().then(membersPayload => {
    // var counter = 1;
    for (var i in respondJson){
        var absencesID = respondJson[i].userId;
        for (var j in membersPayload){
            var membersID = membersPayload[j].userId;
            if (absencesID == membersID){
                var nameValue = membersPayload[j].name;
                JSON.stringify(nameValue);
                respondJson[i]["name"] = nameValue;
                // console.log(counter + ": " + membersPayload[j].name);
                // counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("ITERATION COMPLETED");
}).catch((err) => console.error('error: ' + error.message));
return respondJson;
};


app.get('/getAbsencesWithNames', async (req, res) => {
    var temp = await includeNames();
    res.end(JSON.stringify(temp, null, "\t"));
    console.log("RESPOND SENT");
});
```

Console output is:

```
RESPOND SENT
ITERATION COMPLETED
```

When i was expecting:

```
ITERATION COMPLETED
RESPOND SENT
```

Comment: `includeNames()` does not `return` anything.

Comment: I don't understand, what does it mean? How can i make it return something?

Comment: See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1541563) It's the same question you have, but more generalized.

Comment: You cannot synchronously return a value that is obtained asynchronously.  Cannot be done.  The non-blocking nature of Javascript's asynchronous functions means that your function returns BEFORE the asynchronous value is even available.  See [the question yours was marked a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for a full explanation of how you have to communicate back the result either by returning a promise or using a callback.  Those are your choices.

Comment: FYI, you should do `return members().then(...)` and put `return respondJson` inside the `.then()` handler.  That will return a promise and your caller will use `await` or `.then()` on that promise to get the resolved value.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I apologize for duplicate, but i have been looking for so many hours for a solution on the internet without finding anything close to what i needed. Specifically, i could not find a real life example with Promises  `.then();`. Everyone was using `setTimeout();` which not useful at all. The code below worked fine for me.

Comment: `function includeNames(){
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  members().then(membersPayload => {
   for (var i in respondJson){
    var absencesID = respondJson[i].userId;
    for (var j in membersPayload){
     var membersID = membersPayload[j].userId;
     if (absencesID == membersID){
      var nameValue = membersPayload[j].name;
      JSON.stringify(nameValue);
      respondJson[i]["name"] = nameValue;
      break;
     }
    }
   }
   console.log("ITERATION COMPLETED");
   resolve(respondJson);
  }).catch((err) => console.error('error: ' + error.message));
 })
};`

Comment: `app.get('/getAbsencesWithNames', (req, res) => {
 includeNames().then((respondJson) => {
  res.end(JSON.stringify(respondJson, null, "\t"));
  console.log("RESPOND SENT");
  });
});`

Answer (score -1):

You have to rewrite your function to return Promise.

```js
function includeNames() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    members().then(membersPayload => {
        // var counter = 1;
        for (var i in respondJson){
            var absencesID = respondJson[i].userId;
            for (var j in membersPayload){
                var membersID = membersPayload[j].userId;
                if (absencesID == membersID){
                    var nameValue = membersPayload[j].name;
                    JSON.stringify(nameValue);
                    respondJson[i]["name"] = nameValue;
                    // console.log(counter + ": " + membersPayload[j].name);
                    // counter++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        resolve(respondJson)
        console.log("ITERATION COMPLETED");
    })
  });
};

// you cant use it as you're using
const result = await includeNames()

// or with Promise chain
includeNames().then(result => console.log(result))
```